# Can't run simple project on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

What I do:

1. File -> New -> New Project
2. Choose Navigation-Based Application (iOS)

When I click at Run I get a message "Build Succeeded" and...nothing else. At last line in output is "Waiting for process *** to launch." but the iPhone sumulator dosen't load. :/

Where is wrong?

Comment: If restarting your Mac doesn't help, then reinstall Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem with the simulator. If you close the simulator manually, it may not work properly. Go to:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

Run the simulator. If this does not work, you can try to restart your MAC and XCODE.

Comment: I made what you said. The problem was that the simulator was started in anather account. When I closed it everything goes ok. :)